# On returning to my file 'Play Rendered Animation' says 'file not found'

Tags: rendering

Earlier I rendered my first ever animation which is grass moving. But I closed the program and went to do my personal things. When I got back to the file and opened it, I clicked play rendered animation but now it says 'file H: blahlbhalbha... png.001-0100.avi not found' or something like that. I checked my folders and I clearly have all the 1-100 png files. Do I have to re-render it because it took about 24 hours because I have a terrible computer. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: If you can find the files in the output folder, import them as a VSE image sequence strip

Comment: If blender fails to play back the file that just rendered, this should be reported in the bug tracker. Please check if you can redo the error with a few low resolution frames.

Answer (score 1):

If you have renamed your animation (if it was outputted to a movie file), then Blender will not be able to recognize it if it doesn't have the original output name. Did you rename your file? (Was it a movie file in the first place, or was it an image sequence?)